# Handle "Lock not granted. Try restarting the transaction" error in TokuMX

Tags: locking, tokumx

We have several parallel processes that might at the same time execute **findAndModify** query to Toku.

This sometimes leads to exception: **Lock not granted. Try restarting the transaction** with the code 16759.

There is an [article](https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/09/18/lock-diagnostics-and-index-usage-statistics-in-tokumx-v1-2-1/) about this error an even a closed bug [ticket](https://tokutek.atlassian.net/browse/MX-476) - but unfortunately neither of them provide info on how to deal with such issue.

So are the approaches to handle such exception?

Otherwise its hard to have parallel processes because we can not rely on the locking mechanism of Toku.